# Separator Page On Print Server

Tags: windows, printing, windows-server-2003-r2

When using seperator pages on a print server only seperator files under system 32 seem to work.

If i move the files from system 32 to the root directory it doesnt append the seperator page, ive tried granting full permissions to the directory but still doesnt append the .SEP file and yes i did update the printers config to the new location.

any idea's as to what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this:

what you need to do is create a folder called SepFiles, you can put this folder anywhere and any folder structure inside SepFiles will work for example

C:\SepFiles

> > folder structure
> >     printer1 >> printer1.sep

would read
C:\SepFiles\printer1\printer1.sep

for some unknown reason windows doesnt like to call a folder which doesnt read SepFiles so if your folder structure was
C:\printer1\printer1.sep

the seperator pages wont be binded as windows cant read the folder, again im unsure as to why.